# How do you check if a file or folder (in my case) has been deleted from your git history?

Tags: git, bfg-repo-cleaner

I used the "BFG Repo Cleaner" to remove a folder (target) I accidentally tracked and pushed to the remote repository, and I am wondering how I can I check if the folder was indeed completely removed from the git history?

Answer (score 1):

Say

```
 git log -- <pathnameOfFolder>
```

If it comes up empty, no commit containing such a folder is reachable.

If you know the name of just one file that used to be in this folder, and if that name is unique across the whole project, it suffices to say

```
 git log -n 1 -- */<filename>
```

If that comes up empty, that file is gone from the history; that will be a major clue that this has worked.

Comment: or `git log --all -- <pathnameOfFolder>` to search across all commits

Comment: Proving a negative is hard, so try it first with something that _does_ exist at some point in the past, so you see what the output would look like if the file were found.

Comment: Good point! If possible, it's even better to test the exact command in an old version of the repo that still has the folder in its history. There you should actually expect an result for the given path. That way you confirm that you spelled it correctly.

Comment: Good idea. If the old remote repo still exists, you could re-clone it and test on that.